# traversing a list of list and multiplying each elements

Tags: python, list

```
    L = [[0.9, 0.7] ,[0.5, 0.6], [1.1, 1.2]]
    a = 0

    for i in L[len(L)-2]:
       a = L[0][i] * L[1][i]
```

I wish to multiply this so that it becomes. This wont work for more than 2 values

(a = 0.9 x 0.5 x 1.1 + 0.7 x 0.6 x 1.2 = 0.999). Basically given a list of list each with same size multiply it.

without imports

Comment: Explain, in your own words, the reasoning behind the `len(L)-2` part, and the multiplication. Suppose there were 100 pairs in L; how many values should you multiply together in each multiplication step, and how many of those results should you add together?

Comment: why did you add *without imports*?

Comment: Forgot to mention it

Comment: personal choice and many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is a version that you can use for lists ans sublists of arbitrary length:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul

L = [[0.9, 0.7], [0.5, 0.6], [1.1, 1.2]]

res = sum(reduce(mul, p, 1) for p in zip(*L))
# 0.999
```

as requested this is a version without imports:

```
s = 0
for items in zip(*L):
    prod = 1
    for factor in items:
        prod *= factor
    s += prod
```

---

#### Explanation:

`zip` selects the corresponding elements of your sublists:

```
for p in zip(*L):
    print(p)
# (0.9, 0.5, 1.1)
# (0.7, 0.6, 1.2)
```

the i use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=reduce#functools.reduce) and `mul` to get the product of the tuples and `sum` them.

Answer (score 2):

the general way:

- zip terms together
- apply product of elements. There's no built-in but you can do that with `reduce`
- in a list comprehension

like this:

```
from functools import reduce
import operator

L = [[0.9, 0.7] ,[0.5, 0.6], [1.1, 1.2]]

result = [reduce(operator.mul,terms,1) for terms in zip(*L)]
```

result:

```
[0.49500000000000005, 0.504]
```

for the sum let's use `sum`:

```
total = sum(reduce(operator.mul,terms,1) for terms in zip(*L))
```

roughly gives:

```
0.999
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
L = [[0.9, 0.7] ,[0.5, 0.6], [1.1, 1.2]]
a = (1, 1)

for i in L:
   a = (a[0] * i[0], a[1] * i[1])

print(a)
```

which gives

> (0.49500000000000005, 0.504)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the pairs you want by swapping rows to columns, which is done with the idiom

```
columns = zip(*rows)
```

Then just implement a `product` (analogous to `sum`)

```
import itertools
import operator

def product(iterable):
    return itertools.reduce(operator.mul, iterable, 1)
    # or:
    # acc = 1
    # for el in iterable:
    #     acc *= el
    # return acc
```

And use a list comprehension.

```
results = sum(product(col) for col in columns)
```

Answer (score 1):

Naive implementation

```
L = [[0.9, 0.7] ,[0.5, 0.6], [1.1, 1.2]]
b = []
for i in range(len(L)) :
    a=1 
    for j in range(len(L[0])):
        a*=L[i][j]
    b.append(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

use functional programming

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> def multiply(x, y):
...     return x * y
>>> L = [[0.9, 0.7] ,[0.5, 0.6], [1.1, 1.2]]
>>> sum([reduce(multiply, item) for item in zip(*L)])
0.9990000000000001
```

Comment: `multiply` is just `operator.mul` fyi :)

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution with numpy:

```
import numpy as np

L = [[0.9, 0.7] ,[0.5, 0.6], [1.1, 1.2]]
L = np.array(L)
np.sum([np.prod(L[:,i]) for i in range(L.shape[1])])
```

Traverse through all columns of the 2d array and calculate prod of each column. Then sum all the results.

**Output**

```
0.9990000000000001
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted you could use `zip` to get `list` of `tuple`s, following way

```
L = [[0.9, 0.7] ,[0.5, 0.6], [1.1, 1.2]]
L2 = list(zip(*L))
print(L2) #[(0.9, 0.5, 1.1), (0.7, 0.6, 1.2)]
```

which could be converted into `list` of `list`s, following way

```
L2 = [list(i) for i in L2]
print(L2) #[[0.9, 0.5, 1.1], [0.7, 0.6, 1.2]]
```

Then if you are using Python2 you could use `reduce`, which without `import` is impossible in Python3, so you need to implement reduce-multiplication yourself, I would do it following way:

```
def mult(x):
    while len(x)>=2: x[:2] = [x[0]*x[1]]
    return x[0]
```

Note that I assumed your list have no less than 1 element and data in your list is correct (might be multipled) and you would not need list anymore after feeding it into `mult`, consider following example:

```
t = [9,5,3]
mt = mult(t)
print(mt) # 135 as you might expect
print(t) # [135] i.e. list with 1 element equal to value returned by mult
```

If this is not issue in this case, you can do:

```
a = sum([mult(i) for i in L2])
print(a) # 0.9990000000000001
```

However if you wish to retain original list and use `mult`, then you could use copy of list, for example:

```
k = [3,10,5]
mk = mult(k[:])
print(mk) # 150
print(k) # [3,10,5]
```

Note that `mult` as showed can be easily reworked to use any arithmetic operation.